# Multiple node references using url-widget

Tags: nodes

I am trying to set up a structure of three content types where two references to one or more parents.

- The main content type is assignment
- The second is assignment_image that references the assignment content-type, this I have solved using the node references url widget.
- The third is assignment_vote. This content-type needs to reference both the assignment and the assignment_image.

I can't figure out how to use the node reference url widget to reference two values. I don't want the user to be able to change these values so the autocomplete/selectboxes are not viable options.

I have thought about doing this using hidden-fields and jQuery but I really would like to be able to use existing modules/code.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can put in the number of values that goes into the reference field, i.e. number of references to other nodes, as part of the content type definition (manage fields). That is at least the case Node Reference. You can also select which content types that can be selected. So pick the content types you need and select how many that the users should be able to pick.